# Can you say "I used everything up"

Tags: word-usage

Given the fact that "use up" already means **to use everything**, can you formulate sentences like this and not sound weird at all?

> What happened to your toothpaste? **I used everything up**.

is it like saying **"sufficient enough"**? maybe too redundant?

Comment: You could, but not really with toothpaste. We would more naturally say "I used it all up".

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not redundant, and it makes sense.

*Use up* does not mean *use everything*, it means *use all of [something]*.

*Use everything* would be a much more general activity.

This means, however, that *I used everything up* is not a normal response to a question about toothpaste. It might fit if the question was "Did you find what you needed to cook dinner?"

Comment: Would "I ran out of it" be more fitting for that context then?

Comment: Yes. Or "I used it all up".